# Declare a class with the same name in two different Swift frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, namespaces

I have 2 Swift frameworks *FrameworkA* and *FrameworkB*. I have another framework *Common*. *Common* has an `open` class `BaseClass`.

*FrameworkA* has an `internal` class `Class` that inherits from `BaseClass`.

If I now try to declare an internal class named `Class` in *FrameworkB* which inherits from `BaseClass`, I get an error saying its an *invalid redeclaration of `Class`*.

I of course tried cleaning the derived data and everything, but no luck. I'm on Swift 3. My current workaround is to name the one in *FrameworkB* differently.

Comment: Maybe you can change the visibility of the class to avoid conflicts? Or why don't you use a different name, with a prefix for example?

Comment: Well `Class` is internal to both frameworks. I cannot make it private since its used in multiple places inside of these frameworks. I checked the generated Swift interface of `FrameworkA`, and I couldn't find the declaration/definition of `Class` in it. Which is as expected. So why does it complain about redeclaring it in `FrameworkB`? As for using a different name, yes thats what I'm doing right now. But it doesn't make sense to me.